# how to disable collapsible in JFace TreeViewer

Tags: java, jface, rcp, treeviewer

I am using JFace treeviewer, would like to know how to disable the ability to collapse items and how to remove the collapsible icon.

Comment: You can't remove the icon ('twistie') shown on the tree nodes.

Comment: are there widgets similar to the tree (indented) without collapse property or the icon? but items should be selectable...

Comment: You could always just use a TableViewer with spaces at the start of the rows. Maybe Eclipse [NatTable](https://eclipse.org/nattable/) can do something.

Comment: doesnt help.. any other suggestions? What i need is to remove the twistie but keep the expanded look and indentation.

Comment: convert your treeViewer to tableViewer is actually the best way to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

Restricting all key events on Tree looks promising but you would loose navigating the tree structure and expand/collapse on tree node and all other functionality.

`tree.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         e.doit = false;
      }
    });`

**Or** also if you use `JTree`,

```
JTree jtree = new JTree();
jtree.setToggleClickCount(0);
```

Comment: OMG !!! tree does not support addKeyListener ? Which version of Java you are using ?

Comment: I am working on the code in this link :    http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet002TreeViewer.java

Comment: I need for JFace TreeViewer.. I am not using JTree